# E-mail stored usernames and passwords via automated PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, html, smtp

I have more than 200 usernames, passwords, and e-mails within an excel sheet as well as a MySQL database. I would like to create a PHP automated script that appends the username and password to a strip of general text and sends it to the e-mail address in the same row.
Is this possible via PHP? I'm brand new to this and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.
Any tips would be most appreciated!

Comment: WHY do you have plaintext passwords? I really hope these are automatically generated and not actually entered by users. If they ARE entered by users you NEED TO CHANGE THIS. It is **completely unacceptable** to store user passwords in a readable/decryptable way! The fact that you have them in an excel sheet which means that humans most likely looked or will look at them just makes it worse.

Comment: This sounds dodgy to me!

Comment: These passwords are encrypted within the database with md5 hashes. These are temporary passwords used for one time logging. Once the user logs in he/she will be asked to immediately change the password. Furthermore, the user cannot change his password unless certain information he enters checks with what is already associated with his username. Really I'm trying to get out primary usernames and temporary passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve the data form the database and then send emails using PHP's `mail` function.

From the PHP Manual:

> Using mail() to send a simple email:
>
> ```
> <?php
> // The message
> $message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
>
> // In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
> $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
>
> // Send
> mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm looking for a way to pull data from either excel and automatically have it append certain fields before mailing them out.

Comment: Does it have to be excel? Or can you use MySQL?

Comment: @msgr: Nope! In fact I prefer MySQL. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. I'm lost at where to start. :(